# php email form with multipule attachments using PEAR

Tags: php, pear

I have created a simple HTML form that I am trying to use PEAR to send multiple attachments once the form is submitted. I'm a noobie when it comes to PHP so I'm a bit in over my head.  Every time I submit the form I only get one of the two attachments (letter_uploaded_file). Any help is appreciated.

```
    <?php 
// Pear library includes
// You should have the pear lib installed
include('PEAR/Mail.php');
include('PEAR/Mail/mime.php');

//Settings 
$max_allowed_file_size = 4096; // size in KB 
$allowed_extensions = array("pdf", "txt", "doc", "docx");
$upload_folder = './uploads/'; //<-- this folder must be writeable by the script
$your_email = 'gradysapp@gmail.com';//<<--  update this to your email address

$errors ='';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//Get the uploaded file information
$names_of_files = array();
$names_of_files[] = basename($_FILES["resume_uploaded_file"]['name']);
$names_of_files[] = basename($_FILES["letter_uploaded_file"]['name']);

//get the file extension of the file
$type_of_uploaded_file = array();
$type_of_uploaded_file[] = basename($_FILES['resume_uploaded_file']['type']);
$type_of_uploaded_file[] = basename($_FILES['letter_uploaded_file']['type']);

$size_of_uploaded_file = array();
$size_of_uploaded_file[] = basename($_FILES["resume_uploaded_file"]["size"]/2048);
$size_of_uploaded_file[] = basename($_FILES["letter_uploaded_file"]["size"]/2048);

///------------Do Validations-------------
if(empty($_POST['name'])||empty($_POST['email']))
{
$errors .= "\n Name and Email are required fields. ";   
}
if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
$errors .= "\n Bad email value!";
}

if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size ) 
{
$errors .= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size";
}

//------ Validate the file extension -----
$allowed_ext = false;
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++) 
{ 
    if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
{
    $allowed_ext = true;        
}
}

if(!$allowed_ext)
{
$errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. ".
" Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
}

//send the email 
if(empty($errors))
{
    //copy the temp. uploaded file to uploads folder
    $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
    $tmp_path = array();
    $tmp_path[] = basename($_FILES["resume_uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]);
    $tmp_path[] = basename($_FILES["letter_uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]);

    if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
    {
    if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
    {
        $errors .= '\n error while moving the uploaded file';
    }
}

//send the email
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$position = $_POST["position"];
$to = $your_email;
$subject="New Job Applicant Submission";
$from = $your_email;
$text = "A user  $name has sent you this message:\n $user_message";
$text .= "Phone: " . $phone . "\n";
$text .= "Email: " . $visitor_email . "\n";
$text .= "Position: " . $position . "\n";

$message = new Mail_mime();
$message->setTXTBody($text);
$message->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file);
$message->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file);
$body = $message->get();
$extraheaders = array("From"=>$from, "Subject"=>$subject,"Reply-To"=>$visitor_email);
$headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);
$mail = Mail::factory("mail");
$mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
    //redirect to 'thank-you page
    header('Location: careers_thank-you.html');
}
}
```

Comment: So what problems are you having? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Everytime I submit the form I only get one of the two attachments (letter_uploaded_file).

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, you are only calling addAttachment once:

```
$message->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file);
```

You will need to do it once for each of your uploaded files.

Also, I would recommend you use move_uploaded_file() instead of copy() to place the uploaded files in their final resting place.

Comment: How would the code be written for this? $message->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file); TWICE? How do I delineate between the two files or do I need to.  I am a newbie and looking for any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're only getting one file because you're using the same variable to handle both files:

```
$name_of_uploaded_file =  basename($_FILES['resume_uploaded_file']['name']);
$name_of_uploaded_file =  basename($_FILES['letter_uploaded_file']['name']);
```

This should be something like:

```
$names_of_files = array();
$names_of_files[] = basename($_FILES['resume_uploaded_file']['name']);
$names_of_files[] = basename($_FILES['letter_uploaded_file']['name']);
```

You'll have to propagate this pattern across the rest of your code and loop through the files when you attach them.

Comment: OK I'm still not getting this. Everytime I click send on the user end I get an error saying "The uploaded file is not supported file type. Only the following file types are supported: pdf,doc,docx,txt" I have verified that both files are indeed supported files. I can present code if needed.

Comment: 2 things:
1. That's not how you should check the file type. Use $_FILE['filename']['type'] to get the mimetype of the file (not the extension) and compare that to an array of mimetypes (again not extensions.
2. Don't loop through the array and check each individually, use in_array().

Comment: How do I write the type array? $type = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "txt");

Comment: Close, but instead of putting the extension in the array, use the mimetype (see http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)